# Adding Clustering into my Google Maps Script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add Map Clustering to my existing script.

I would like to add this code, and blend it into my existing code.

Code - Working example of script below. https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/advanced_example.html

```
<script>
      var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/markerclusterer';
      if (document.location.search.indexOf('compiled') !== -1) {
        script += '_compiled';
      }
      script += '.js"><' + '/script>';
      document.write(script);
    </script>

    <script>
      var styles = [[{
        url: '../images/people35.png',
        height: 35,
        width: 35,
        anchor: [16, 0],
        textColor: '#ff00ff',
        textSize: 10
      }, {
        url: '../images/people45.png',
        height: 45,
        width: 45,
        anchor: [24, 0],
        textColor: '#ff0000',
        textSize: 11
      }, {
        url: '../images/people55.png',
        height: 55,
        width: 55,
        anchor: [32, 0],
        textColor: '#ffffff',
        textSize: 12
      }], [{
        url: '../images/conv30.png',
        height: 27,
        width: 30,
        anchor: [3, 0],
        textColor: '#ff00ff',
        textSize: 10
      }, {
        url: '../images/conv40.png',
        height: 36,
        width: 40,
        anchor: [6, 0],
        textColor: '#ff0000',
        textSize: 11
      }, {
        url: '../images/conv50.png',
        width: 50,
        height: 45,
        anchor: [8, 0],
        textSize: 12
      }], [{
        url: '../images/heart30.png',
        height: 26,
        width: 30,
        anchor: [4, 0],
        textColor: '#ff00ff',
        textSize: 10
      }, {
        url: '../images/heart40.png',
        height: 35,
        width: 40,
        anchor: [8, 0],
        textColor: '#ff0000',
        textSize: 11
      }, {
        url: '../images/heart50.png',
        width: 50,
        height: 44,
        anchor: [12, 0],
        textSize: 12
      }]];

      var markerClusterer = null;
      var map = null;
      var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' +
          'chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';

      function refreshMap() {
        if (markerClusterer) {
          markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
        }

        var markers = [];

        var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,
          new google.maps.Size(24, 32));

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
              data.photos[i].longitude)
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            draggable: true,
            icon: markerImage
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }

        var zoom = parseInt(document.getElementById('zoom').value, 10);
        var size = parseInt(document.getElementById('size').value, 10);
        var style = parseInt(document.getElementById('style').value, 10);
        zoom = zoom === -1 ? null : zoom;
        size = size === -1 ? null : size;
        style = style === -1 ? null: style;

        markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
          maxZoom: zoom,
          gridSize: size,
          styles: styles[style]
        });
      }

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.91, 116.38),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var refresh = document.getElementById('refresh');
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(refresh, 'click', refreshMap);

        var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(clear, 'click', clearClusters);

        refreshMap();
      }

      function clearClusters(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

I then would like to take the above code and add the clustering to my existing code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

                    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.701829, -122.179969);
                    var map;

                 map_initialize(); 

        function map_initialize()
        {
                    var googleMapOptions = 
                    { 
                        center: mapCenter, // map center
                        zoom: 13,
                        maxZoom: 22,
                        minZoom: 10,
                            zoomControlOptions: {
                                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                        },

                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            styles: [{
            stylers: [{
                saturation: -100
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: "water",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [{
                color: "#0099dd"
            }]
        }, {
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [{
                visibility: "off"
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: "poi.park",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [{
                color: "#aadd55"
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: "road.highway",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [{
                visibility: "on"
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: "road.arterial",
            elementType: "labels.text",
            stylers: [{
                visibility: "on"
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: "road.local",
            elementType: "labels.text",
            stylers: [{
                visibility: "on"
            }]
        }, {}] 
                        };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), googleMapOptions);            

            $.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
                $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
                    var pin_firstname           = $(this).attr('pin_firstname');
                    var pincore_fulladdress     = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('pincore_fulladdress') +'</p>';
                    var pin_status              = $(this).attr('pin_status');
                    var point                   = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('pincore_lat')),parseFloat($(this).attr('pincore_lng')));
                        create_marker(point, pin_firstname, pincore_fulladdress, false, false, false, "icons/pin_blue.png");
                });


            }); 

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                    var EditForm = '<p><div class="marker-edit">'+
                                    '<form action="ajax-save.php" method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">'+
                                    '<label for="pPinStatus"><span>Status:</span> <select name="pPinStatus" class="save-type"><option value="Sold">SOLD</option><option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>'+
                                    '<option value="house">Rejected</option></select></label>'+
                                    '<label for="pFullName"><span>Customer Name:</span><input type="text" name="pFullName" class="save-name" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="40" /></label>'+
                                    '<label for="pDesc"><span>Address :</span><textarea name="pDesc" class="save-desc" placeholder="Enter Address" maxlength="150"></textarea></label>'+
                                    '</form>'+
                                    '</div></p><button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">Save Marker</button>';

                create_marker(event.latLng, 'Add New Pin', EditForm, true, true, true, "icons/pin_green.png");
            });

    }

    function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc,  InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconPath, mType)
    {                 


                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: MapPos,
                        map: map,
                        draggable:DragAble,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        icon: iconPath

        });

                    var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
                                            '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
                                            '<h1 class="marker-heading">'+mType+'</h1>'+
                                            MapTitle+
                                            MapDesc+

                                            '</span><button name="remove-marker" class="remove-marker">Remove Marker</button>'+
                                            '</div></div>');    


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowindow.setContent(contentString[0]);

        var removeBtn   = contentString.find('button.remove-marker')[0];
        var saveBtn     = contentString.find('button.save-marker')[0];

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(removeBtn, "click", function(event) {
            remove_marker(marker);
        });

        if(typeof saveBtn !== 'undefined') 
        {
            //add click listner to save marker button
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(saveBtn, "click", function(event) {
                var mReplace = contentString.find('span.info-content'); 
                var mName = contentString.find('input.save-name')[0].value; 
                var mDesc  = contentString.find('textarea.save-desc')[0].value; 
                var mType = contentString.find('select.save-type')[0].value;

                if(mName =='' || mDesc =='')
                {
                    alert("Please enter the correct information to disposition a new pin!");
                }else{
                    save_marker(marker, mName, mDesc, mType, mReplace); 
                }
            });
        }


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: MapPos,
                        map: map,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        icon: iconPath


                });
                infowindow.open(map,marker); 
        });

        if(InfoOpenDefault) 
        {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        }
    }

    function remove_marker(Marker)
    {


        if(Marker.getDraggable()) 
        {
            Marker.setMap(null);
        }
        else
        {
            var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); 
            var myData = {del : 'true', latlang : mLatLang};
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "map_process.php",
              data: myData,
              success:function(data){
                    Marker.setMap(null); 
                    alert(data);
                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(thrownError); 
                }
            });
        }

    }

    function save_marker(Marker, mName, mAddress, mType, replaceWin)
            {
                var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); 
                var myData = {pin_firstname : mName, pincore_fulladdress : mAddress, latlang : mLatLang, pin_status : mType }; 
                    console.log(replaceWin);        
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "map_process.php",
                        data: myData,
                    success:function(data){
                        replaceWin.html(data); 
                            Marker.setDraggable(false); 
                            Marker.setIcon('icons/pin_blue.png'); 
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError); 
            }
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you take a peak at this please. I haven't had any luck, and you seem to be the kind of person that could do this in their sleep @kjy112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an array of markers first, push every created marker there and then call markerClusterer over that array. This approach worked for me once and that's exactly what is suggested in the code froom googlemaps you listed:

```
var markers = [];
function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc,  InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconPath, mType)
{                 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: MapPos,
        map: map,
        draggable:DragAble,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: iconPath

    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

run create_marker function (in your case after parsing ajax data) and then create clusters like

```
markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
      maxZoom: zoom,
      gridSize: size,
      styles: styles[style]
    });
```

You might want to call refreshMap() when using remove_marker() or save_marker() functions to update markerClusterer object.

be sure to include jQuery, Google maps API and markerclusterer script. Here's the complete output from my codepen:

```js
 var infoWindows = [];
 var markers = [];
 var markerClusterer = null;
 var map = null;
 var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' + 'chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';
 var pinIcon = "icons/pin_green.png";
 var pinIcon = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' + 'chco=FFFFFF,00FF8C,000000&ext=.png';

 function refreshMap() {
   if (markerClusterer) {
     markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
     //     markerClusterer.addMarkers(markers,true)
     markerClusterer.addMarkers(markers)
   }
 }

 function clearClusters(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
   }
   //////////custom code
 var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.701829, -122.179969);
 var map;

 function map_initialize() {
   var googleMapOptions = {
     center: mapCenter, // map center
     zoom: 13,
     maxZoom: 22,
     minZoom: 4,
     zoomControlOptions: {
       style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
       position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
     },
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
     styles: roadmap_styles
   };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), googleMapOptions);
   $.get("map_process.php", function(data) {
     $(data).find("marker").each(function() {
       var pin_firstname = $(this).attr('pin_firstname');
       var pincore_fulladdress = '<p>' + $(this).attr('pincore_fulladdress') + '</p>';
       var pin_status = $(this).attr('pin_status');
       var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('pincore_lat')), parseFloat($(this).attr('pincore_lng')));
       create_marker(point, pin_firstname, pincore_fulladdress, false, false, false, "icons/pin_blue.png");
     });
   });
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
     var EditForm = '<p><div class="marker-edit">' +
       '<form action="ajax-save.php" method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">' +
       '<label for="pPinStatus"><span>Status:</span> <select name="pPinStatus" class="save-type"><option value="Sold">SOLD</option><option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>' +
       '<option value="house">Rejected</option></select></label><br/>' +
       '<label for="pFullName"><span>Customer Name:</span><input type="text" name="pFullName" class="save-name" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="40" /></label>' +
       '<label for="pDesc"><span>Address :</span><textarea name="pDesc" class="save-desc" placeholder="Enter Address" maxlength="150"></textarea></label>' +
       '</form>' +
       '</div></p><button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">Save Marker</button>';
     create_marker(event.latLng, 'Add New Pin', EditForm, true, true, true, pinIcon);
   });
   markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
     maxZoom: 15,
     gridSize: 4,
     styles: clusterer_styles
   });
   $('#refresh').click(function() {
     refreshMap()
   })
   $('#clear').click(function() {
     clearClusters()
   })
 }

 function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc, InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconPath, mType) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: MapPos,
     map: map,
     draggable: DragAble,
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     icon: iconPath
   });
   markers.push(marker);
   console.log(markers)
   refreshMap()
   var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">' +
     '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">' +
     '<h1 class="marker-heading">' + mType + '</h1>' +
     MapTitle +
     MapDesc +
     '</span><button name="remove-marker" class="remove-marker">Remove Marker</button>' +
     '</div></div>');
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   infowindow.setContent(contentString[0]);
   var removeBtn = contentString.find('button.remove-marker')[0];
   var saveBtn = contentString.find('button.save-marker')[0];
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(removeBtn, "click", function(event) {
     remove_marker(marker);
   });
   if (typeof saveBtn !== 'undefined') {
     //add click listner to save marker button
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(saveBtn, "click", function(event) {
       var mReplace = contentString.find('span.info-content');
       var mName = contentString.find('input.save-name')[0].value;
       var mDesc = contentString.find('textarea.save-desc')[0].value;
       var mType = contentString.find('select.save-type')[0].value;
       if (mName == '' || mDesc == '') {
         alert("Please enter the correct information to disposition a new pin!");
       } else {
         save_marker(marker, mName, mDesc, mType, mReplace);
       }
     });
   }
   infoWindows.push(infowindow)
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     for (var a in infoWindows) {
       infoWindows[a].close()
     }
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });
   if (InfoOpenDefault) {
     for (var a in infoWindows) {
       infoWindows[a].close()
     }
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }
 }

 function remove_marker(Marker) {
   if (Marker.getDraggable()) {
     Marker.setMap(null);
   } else {
     var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue();
     var myData = {
       del: 'true',
       latlang: mLatLang
     };
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "map_process.php",
       data: myData,
       success: function(data) {
         Marker.setMap(null);
         alert(data);
       },
       error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert(thrownError);
       }
     });
   }
 }

 function save_marker(Marker, mName, mAddress, mType, replaceWin) {
   var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue();
   var myData = {
     pin_firstname: mName,
     pincore_fulladdress: mAddress,
     latlang: mLatLang,
     pin_status: mType
   };
   console.log(replaceWin);
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "map_process.php",
     data: myData,
     success: function(data) {
       replaceWin.html(data);
       Marker.setDraggable(false);
       Marker.setIcon('icons/pin_blue.png');
     },
     error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       alert(thrownError);
     }
   });
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {
   map_initialize();
 });
 var clusterer_styles = [
   [{
     url: imageUrl,
     height: 35,
     width: 35,
     anchor: [16, 0],
     textColor: '#ff00ff',
     textSize: 10
   }, {
     url: imageUrl,
     height: 45,
     width: 45,
     anchor: [24, 0],
     textColor: '#ff0000',
     textSize: 11
   }, {
     url: imageUrl,
     height: 55,
     width: 55,
     anchor: [32, 0],
     textColor: '#ffffff',
     textSize: 12
   }],
   [{
     url: imageUrl,
     height: 27,
     width: 30,
     anchor: [3, 0],
     textColor: '#ff00ff',
     textSize: 10
   }, {
     url: imageUrl,
     height: 36,
     width: 40,
     anchor: [6, 0],
     textColor: '#ff0000',
     textSize: 11
   }, {
     url: imageUrl,
     width: 50,
     height: 45,
     anchor: [8, 0],
     textSize: 12
   }],
   [{
     url: imageUrl,
     height: 26,
     width: 30,
     anchor: [4, 0],
     textColor: '#ff00ff',
     textSize: 10
   }, {
     url: imageUrl,
     height: 35,
     width: 40,
     anchor: [8, 0],
     textColor: '#ff0000',
     textSize: 11
   }, {
     url: imageUrl,
     width: 50,
     height: 44,
     anchor: [12, 0],
     textSize: 12
   }]
 ];
 var roadmap_styles = [{
   stylers: [{
     saturation: -100
   }]
 }, {
   featureType: "water",
   elementType: "geometry.fill",
   stylers: [{
     color: "#0099dd"
   }]
 }, {
   elementType: "labels",
   stylers: [{
     visibility: "off"
   }]
 }, {
   featureType: "poi.park",
   elementType: "geometry.fill",
   stylers: [{
     color: "#aadd55"
   }]
 }, {
   featureType: "road.highway",
   elementType: "labels",
   stylers: [{
     visibility: "on"
   }]
 }, {
   featureType: "road.arterial",
   elementType: "labels.text",
   stylers: [{
     visibility: "on"
   }]
 }, {
   featureType: "road.local",
   elementType: "labels.text",
   stylers: [{
     visibility: "on"
   }]
 }, {}]
```

```css
#map{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
 }
 html,
 body
 {
  height: 100%;
 }
 
 .button
 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background: #b5cdde;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 3vw;
  z-index: 50;
  line-height: 3rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #aac;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid darken(#b5cdde,10%);
 }
 .button:hover
 {
  background: darken(#b5cdde,10%)
 }
 .button:nth-child(2)
 {
  right: 13vw;
 }
 .marker-edit
 {
  width: 10vw;
 }
```

```html
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0.2/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
<div class='button' id='refresh'>
  Refresh
</div>
<div class='button' id='clear'>
  Clear
</div>
```

Comment: All of this happens inside your `map_initialize()` function, though I'd recommend to define `markers` array before jQuery document ready event so you could access it from browser console. I'll provide a codepen  with my understanding of your code a bit later, feel free to fork it to match your needs

Comment: have you had a chance to take a peak at this @obojdi

Comment: [here you are](http://codepen.io/obojdi/pen/KdNjOj)
this answer might also be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258553/adding-simple-marker-clusterer-to-google-map I've made some improvements on your code like putting all infoWindows into global array so you can hide all but active one. Let me know if you have further questions and sorry for late response

Comment: the point is, you should flush `markerClusterer` using `.clearMarkers()` method and then pass global `markers` array to it. Note: passing boolean true as second parameter to `.addMarkers(markers)` will force clusters to redraw